# I am not getting data out of a fixed range in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

In my crystal report, I am actually filtering the data based on start date and end date.
But I am not getting data out of a fixed range(1-1-1985 to 31-12-2009).
Data I am getting is directly from DB table, I am not calling any procedure.

I checked all possible way to restrict/filter the data, I could not find anywhere they are filtering in the report.Still I am getting data from 1985 to 2009.

I am using Crystal Report 8.0.
Any idea how and where the data can be filtered out??

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you sure your date field is of type date? If it is a string field, you'll have to convert it first.

Comment: @bidya, Have you tried verifying the database from within the report designer?

Comment: I am able to get the data when I query the same SQL expression in SQL developer. Data is proper and even query present in the Crystal Report is also fine. This report filters the data based on input parameter(start and end date), which is doing perfect if I am filtering within the range.

In report preview also I am getting filtered data.

When I verified the database it gives me 2 empty string error message.

Comment: @bidya, you should mark your response as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and now it is working fine.
Menu=> Database>Show SQL Query...>Reset
then I saved the report.

It is working fine now.

I feel it is a bug in Crystal Report or may be the behavior of the software(because I am new to crystal report).